# java get the first date and last date of given month and given year

Tags: java, date, calendar

I am trying to get the first date and the last date of the given month and year. I used the following code to get the last date in the format yyyyMMdd. But couldnot get this format. Also then I want the start date in the same format. I am still working on this. Can anyone help me in fixing the below code.

```
public static java.util.Date calculateMonthEndDate(int month, int year) {
    int[] daysInAMonth = { 29, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };
    int day = daysInAMonth[month];
    boolean isLeapYear = new GregorianCalendar().isLeapYear(year);

    if (isLeapYear && month == 2) {
        day++;
    }
    GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar(year, month - 1, day);
    java.util.Date monthEndDate = new java.util.Date(gc.getTime().getTime());
    return monthEndDate;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int month = 3;
    int year = 2076;
    final java.util.Date calculatedDate = calculateMonthEndDate(month, year);
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
    format.format(calculatedDate);
    System.out.println("Calculated month end date : " + calculatedDate);
}
```

Comment: Well what results *are* you getting? And why are you converting from a `Date` (the result of `Calendar.getTime()` to a `long`, and then creating a new `Date`)? And could you switch to using Joda Time, which would make all of this much neater?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the **Start Date**

```
    GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar(year, month-1, 1);
    java.util.Date monthEndDate = new java.util.Date(gc.getTime().getTime());
    System.out.println(monthEndDate);
```

(***Note*** :  in the Start date the **day** =1)

for the formatted

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(/////////add your format here);
System.out.println("Calculated month end date : " + format.format(calculatedDate));
```

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), `GregorianCalendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 24):

## `java.time.YearMonth` methods `atDay` & `atEndOfMonth`

The [java.time framework](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) built into Java 8+ ([Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html)) has commands for this.

The aptly-named [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/YearMonth.html) class represents a month of a year, without any specific day or time. From there we can ask for the first and days of the month.

```
YearMonth yearMonth = YearMonth.of( 2015, 1 );     // 2015-01. January of 2015.
LocalDate firstOfMonth = yearMonth.atDay( 1 );     // 2015-01-01
LocalDate lastOfMonth = yearMonth.atEndOfMonth();  // 2015-01-31
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later
- Built-in.
- Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
- Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)
- Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))
- Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
- For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 8):

Simply you can use Calendar class. you should assign month variable which month you want

```
        Calendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
        gc.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        gc.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        Date monthStart = gc.getTime();
        gc.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
        gc.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
        Date monthEnd = gc.getTime();
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");

        System.out.println("Calculated month start date : " + format.format(monthStart));
        System.out.println("Calculated month end date : " + format.format(monthEnd));
```

Answer (score 7):

**First day:**

```
Calendar.getInstance().getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

**Last day of month:**

```
Calendar.getInstance().getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
format.format(calculatedDate);
System.out.println("Calculated month end date : " + calculatedDate);
```

Change it to

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
String formattedDate =  format.format(calculatedDate);
System.out.println("Calculated month end date : " + formattedDate);
```

For more detail

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format(java.util.Date)

Another Approach

```
package com.shashi.mpoole;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat; 
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class DateMagic {

     public static String PATTERN = "yyyyMMdd";

     static class Measure {
           private int month;
           private int year;
           private Calendar calendar;

           public Measure build() {

                calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.set(year, month, 1);

                return this;
           }

           public Measure(int year, int month) {
                this.year(year);
                this.month(month);
           }

           public String min() {
                  return format(calendar.getActualMinimum(Calendar.DATE));
           }

           public String max() {
                  return format(calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DATE));
           }

           private Date date(GregorianCalendar c) {
                  return new java.util.Date(c.getTime().getTime());

           }

           private GregorianCalendar gc(int day) {
                  return new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day);
           }

           private String format(int day) {

                  SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(PATTERN);
                  return format.format(date(gc(day)));
           }

           public void month(int month) {
                  this.month = month - 1;
           }

           public void year(int year) {
                  this.year = year;
           }
      }

      public static void main(String[] args) {

             Measure measure = new Measure(2020, 6).build();

             System.out.println(measure.min());
             System.out.println(measure.max());

        
    }

}
```

Comment: This does not work properly. Try passing 6th month which is june. You will get first date 2020-06-01 and end date 2020-07-01.

Comment: Thanks @Sadda Hussain . Issue fixed.

Answer (score 4):

Try below code for last day of month : -

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();      
c.set(2012,3,1); //------>  
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, c.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));  

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");  
System.out.println(sdf.format(c.getTime()));
```

http://www.coderanch.com/t/385759/java/java/date-date-month

Answer (score 2):

Although, not exactly the answer for the OP question, below methods will given **current month** first & last dates as Java 8+ LocalDate instances.

```
public static LocalDate getCurrentMonthFirstDate() {
    return LocalDate.ofEpochDay(System.currentTimeMillis() / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) ).withDayOfMonth(1);
}

public static LocalDate getCurrentMonthLastDate() {
    return LocalDate.ofEpochDay(System.currentTimeMillis() / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) ).plusMonths(1).withDayOfMonth(1).minusDays(1);
}
```

*Side note: Using `LocalDate.ofEpochDay(...)` instead of `LocalDate.now()` gives much improved performance. Also, using the millis-in-a-day expression instead of the end value, which is `86400000` is performing better. I initially thought the latter would perform better than the the expression :P*

**Why this answer**:  *Even this is not a correct answer for OP question,  I m still answering here as Google showed this question when I searched for 'java 8 get month start date' :)*

Answer (score 1):

```
        GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar(year, selectedMonth-1, 1);
           java.util.Date monthStartDate = new java.util.Date(gc.getTime().getTime());
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(monthStartDate);
        calendar.add(calendar.MONTH, 1);
        calendar.add(calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
           java.util.Date monthEndDate = new java.util.Date(calendar.getTime())
```

Comment: Your answer should contains an explanation of your code and a description how it solves the problem.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
public static Date[] getMonthInterval(Date data) throws Exception {

    Date[] dates = new Date[2];

    Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance();

    start.setTime(data);
    start.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, start.getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    start.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    start.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    start.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    end.setTime(data);
    end.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, end.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    end.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
    end.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
    end.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);

    //System.out.println("start "+ start.getTime());
    //System.out.println("end   "+ end.getTime());

    dates[0] = start.getTime();
    dates[1] = end.getTime();

    return dates;
}
```

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).