# How to get Start date and end date of month?

Tags: android, android-calendar

i am using this libs [CalnderView](https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview/wiki) any one know how to get end and last date of month?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java get the first date and last date of given month and given year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14475489/java-get-the-first-date-and-last-date-of-given-month-and-given-year)

Comment: I downvote because the question is unclear: this month, any month? As limits on the calendar view or just into your code? Also because I see no search, no research, no attempt to solve your problem yourself.

Comment: okay thanks for guide me i'll remember in future .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Its not about any library** but you can get it as.

```
Calendar.getInstance().getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

This returns actual maximum for current month.

Comment: why people give down vote on my question ? is it wrong question?

Comment: @mykieejass sometimes people don't do that... thats the question asking standard of SOF... read about that in description of sof.. :)

Comment: That’s the old-fashioned way. You may prefer `LocalDate.now(yourTimeZone).with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth())`. If your Android version is new (API level 26 or higher) or you can afford an external library (search for ThreeTenABP).

Answer (score 2):

```
Used getDaterange method to get the stat and end date in month. its work for me.

public Pair<Date, Date> getDateRange() {
    Date begining, end;

    {
        Calendar calendar = getCalendarForNow();
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,
                calendar.getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        setTimeToBeginningOfDay(calendar);
        begining = calendar.getTime();
    }

    {
        Calendar calendar = getCalendarForNow();
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,
                calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        setTimeToEndofDay(calendar);
        end = calendar.getTime();
    }

    return Pair.of(begining, end);
}

private static Calendar getCalendarForNow() {
    Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(new Date());
    return calendar;
}

private static void setTimeToBeginningOfDay(Calendar calendar) {
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
}

private static void setTimeToEndofDay(Calendar calendar) {
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_D`enter code here`AY, 23);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 999);
}
```